# How to move text to be next to post CSS animation object

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have a webpage with a row of images in an inline block. Here is a picture of the images.

[image]

I have an animation setup so when you click on an image it slides to the right like this:

[image]

What I would like is for the text to float to the left and be next to the image. I have tried float left but that doesn't work. Here is the jquery I am using to input the HTML:

```
 $(this).after("<h3 style='display: inline'>testgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</h3>");
```

And here is the CSS for the images:

```
.imageFace {
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
-webkit-animation: animation 2000ms linear both;
animation: animation 2000ms linear both;
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

And here is the html for the images:

```
<div style="width:1000px;margin:0px auto;color:white;clear: both;">
        <h2 id="after">Our Team</h2>
        <div id="faces">
            <img src="facePlacehold.gif" class="imageFace" id="1">
            <img src="facePlacehold.gif" class="imageFace" id="2">
            <img src="facePlacehold.gif" class="imageFace" id="3">
            <img src="facePlacehold.gif" class="imageFace" id="4">
            <img src="facePlacehold.gif" class="imageFace" id="5">
            <img src="facePlacehold.gif" class="imageFace" id="6">
            <img src="facePlacehold.gif" class="imageFace" id="7">
            <img src="facePlacehold.gif" class="imageFace" id="8">
            <img src="facePlacehold.gif" class="imageFace" id="9">
            <img src="facePlacehold.gif" class="imageFace" id="10">
            <img src="facePlacehold.gif" class="imageFace" id="11">
            <img src="facePlacehold.gif" class="imageFace" id="12">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have uploaded the website to github: http://thomfur.github.io/

Here is the source: https://github.com/thomfur/thomfur.github.io

Comment: write your js code to help you. and if you can create a demo for it

Comment: Ok I have created a demo for it and all the source